# cmake fixup_bundle doesn't say why it's failing

Tags: linux, qt, cmake, cpack

I have a cmake project that uses Qt libraries and I need to build it on a few different systems.  I've configured the cmake project it to install library dependencies using *fixup_bundle*.  This works on some systems but fails on others and I can't tell why.

I'm including the locations of all the library dependencies in the 3rd param of fixup_bundle, and it doesn't seem to have any trouble finding libraries or copying them to the install directory.  And as stated above, on some systems it all works fine.

On the systems where it fails it lists the Qt libs as *external prerequisites*.  I don't know why though.  It copies all the Qt libs to the install dir.  It also copies the libs which the QT libs depend on to the install dir.  So I don't understand what the problem is.

```
make install
...
[100%] Built target my_project_executable
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/./libgenerated-proto.so
-- Installing: /build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/./libicudata.so
-- Installing: /build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/./libicudata.so.64
-- Installing: /build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/./libicudata.so.64.1
-- Installing: /build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/./libicui18n.so
-- Installing: /build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/./libicui18n.so.64
-- Installing: /build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/./libicui18n.so.64.1
-- Installing: /build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/./libicuuc.so
-- Installing: /build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/./libicuuc.so.64
-- Installing: /build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/./libicuuc.so.64.1
-- Installing: /build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/./libicutu.so
-- Installing: /build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/./libicutu.so.64
-- Installing: /build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/./libicutu.so.64.1
-- Installing: /build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/./libssl.so
-- Installing: /build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/./libssl.so.1.1
-- Installing: /build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/./libcrypto.so
-- Installing: /build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/./libcrypto.so.1.1
-- Installing: /build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/./my_project_executable
-- fixup_bundle
--   app='/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/my_project_executable'
--   libs=''
--   dirs='/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir;/build/workspace/my_project/build/lib;/opt/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/lib'
--   ignoreItems=''
-- fixup_bundle: preparing...
-- fixup_bundle: copying...
-- 1/40: *NOT* copying '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/my_project_executable'
-- 2/40: copying '/home/build/gcc5/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1'
-- 3/40: linking '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libstdc++.so.6.0.21' -> '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libstdc++.so.6'
-- 4/40: linking '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5Core.so.5.6.1' -> '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5Core.so.5'
-- 5/40: linking '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5Network.so.5.6.1' -> '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5Network.so.5'
-- 6/40: linking '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5Sql.so.5.6.1' -> '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5Sql.so.5'
-- 7/40: linking '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5Xml.so.5.6.1' -> '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5Xml.so.5'
-- 8/40: linking '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5.6.1' -> '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5'
-- 9/40: linking '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libicudata.so.56.1' -> '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libicudata.so.56'
-- 10/40: linking '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libicui18n.so.56.1' -> '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libicui18n.so.56'
-- 11/40: linking '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libicuuc.so.56.1' -> '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libicuuc.so.56'
-- 12/40: copying '/home/build/gcc5/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.21'
-- 13/40: copying '/opt/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.6.1'
-- Removed runtime path from "/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5Core.so.5.6.1"
-- 14/40: copying '/opt/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Network.so.5.6.1'
-- Removed runtime path from "/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5Network.so.5.6.1"
-- 15/40: copying '/opt/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Sql.so.5.6.1'
-- Removed runtime path from "/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5Sql.so.5.6.1"
-- 16/40: copying '/opt/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Xml.so.5.6.1'
-- Removed runtime path from "/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5Xml.so.5.6.1"
-- 17/40: copying '/opt/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5.6.1'
-- Removed runtime path from "/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5.6.1"
-- 18/40: copying '/opt/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libicudata.so.56.1'
-- Removed runtime path from "/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libicudata.so.56.1"
-- 19/40: copying '/opt/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so.56.1'
-- Removed runtime path from "/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libicui18n.so.56.1"
-- 20/40: copying '/opt/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.56.1'
-- Removed runtime path from "/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libicuuc.so.56.1"
-- fixup_bundle: fixing...
-- 21/40: fix-up not required on this platform '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/my_project_executable'
-- 22/40: fix-up not required on this platform '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libgcc_s.so.1'
-- 23/40: fix-up not required on this platform '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libstdc++.so.6'
-- 24/40: fix-up not required on this platform '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5Core.so.5'
-- 25/40: fix-up not required on this platform '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5Network.so.5'
-- 26/40: fix-up not required on this platform '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5Sql.so.5'
-- 27/40: fix-up not required on this platform '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5Xml.so.5'
-- 28/40: fix-up not required on this platform '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5'
-- 29/40: fix-up not required on this platform '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libicudata.so.56'
-- 30/40: fix-up not required on this platform '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libicui18n.so.56'
-- 31/40: fix-up not required on this platform '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libicuuc.so.56'
-- 32/40: fix-up not required on this platform '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libstdc++.so.6.0.21'
-- 33/40: fix-up not required on this platform '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5Core.so.5.6.1'
-- 34/40: fix-up not required on this platform '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5Network.so.5.6.1'
-- 35/40: fix-up not required on this platform '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5Sql.so.5.6.1'
-- 36/40: fix-up not required on this platform '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5Xml.so.5.6.1'
-- 37/40: fix-up not required on this platform '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5.6.1'
-- 38/40: fix-up not required on this platform '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libicudata.so.56.1'
-- 39/40: fix-up not required on this platform '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libicui18n.so.56.1'
-- 40/40: fix-up not required on this platform '/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libicuuc.so.56.1'
-- fixup_bundle: cleaning up...
-- fixup_bundle: verifying...
-- ===========================================================================
-- Analyzing app='/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/my_project_executable'
-- bundle='/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir'
-- executable='/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/my_project_executable'
-- valid='1'
-- executable file 1: /build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/libQt5Core.so.5.6.1
-- executable file 2: /build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/my_project_executable
-- verified='0'
-- info='external prerequisites found:
f='/build/workspace/my_project/build/install_dir/my_project_executable'
external_prereqs='/opt/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5;/opt/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Network.so.5;/opt/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Sql.so.5;/opt/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Xml.so.5;/opt/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5'
'
-- 
CMake Error at /home/build/cmake-3.17.1/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/BundleUtilities.cmake:1119 (message):
  error: verify_app failed
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/build/cmake-3.17.1/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/BundleUtilities.cmake:986 (verify_app)
  src/server/cmake_install.cmake:47 (fixup_bundle)
  cmake_install.cmake:81 (include)


make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I know there are 2 different versions of ICU libraries here.  My project uses ICU and it's using version 64.  The Qt libs reference an older version of ICU libs.  The ICU lib files have the version in the file name so this shouldn't be a problem and it doesn't seem to be causing issues on the system where fixup_bundle is working.

Hopefully someone out there knows what fixup_bundle is choking on and can help.  I'm currently stumped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be OS specific.  The cmake project was configured to rename the executable from ${PROJECT_NAME} to ${PROJECT_NAME}.bin during the install, so it was using:

```
install(PROGRAMS ... RENAME ${PROJECT_NAME}.bin)
```

instead of:

```
install(TARGETS ...)
```

This results in the RPATH being left as-is in the installed binary.  Having the hard-coded RPATH in the installed binary only caused problems for fixup_bundle on our CentOS build machine.  My local development machine (which does not use CentOS) had no problem.

Anyway, I reconfigured the project so it no longer renamed the project executable and just used the standard **install(TARGETS ...)** paradigm and now fixup_bundle is able to bundle up the package without problems.